# How to set full url dynamically in http request connector in Mule

Tags: http, mule, hateoas

As shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37462195/mule-how-to-dynamically-set-a-url-on-an-http-request-endpoint), it is possible to have parts of the url in variables, when requesting an http endpoint with mule.

But I have a full url, returned from an endpoint supporting hateoas. Is it possible to use this full url for requests without splitting it up into several parts (host, port, path)?

With full url I mean sth. like "http://example.com/a/specific/path" instead of host="example.com", port="80", path="/a/specific/path"

Comment: I created a ticket for this in mule jira: https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-10741

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple way to do is to split the url into multiple parts and set it into a flow variables. Then you can use this flow variables anywhere you want.

An simple example to do it is as follows:-

```
 <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <flow name="csv-to-smtpFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/aa" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <set-payload value="http://example.com:80/a/specific/path" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <set-variable variableName="url" value="#[new URL(payload);]" doc:name="Variable"/>
        <set-variable variableName="protocol" value="#[url.getProtocol();]" doc:name="Variable"/>
        <set-variable variableName="host" value="#[url.getHost();]" doc:name="Variable"/>
        <set-variable variableName="port" value="#[url.getPort();]" doc:name="Variable"/>
        <set-variable variableName="path" value="#[url.getPath();]" doc:name="Variable"/>
        <logger message="Done" level="INFO"/>
    </flow>
```

Here  you can see I am setting the url http://example.com:80/a/specific/path in a payload and then splitting it into host, port, path etc and storing it in variables.

**Pls note** if your url is in the form http://example.com:80/a/specific/path, you will get the port using expression `#[url.getProtocol();]`
But if your url is in the form http://example.com/a/specific/path, you will not get the port number.

Ref:- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/urlInfo.html

Comment: Thank you for your response. But as described in the question I was hoping to find a solution without splitting the url. So I will not accept your answer for now and wait if someone has another solution for this